# setInterval inside conditional statement jQuery

Tags: jquery, if-statement, setinterval

I have an image that translates with the user scroll. If the image stays on a specific place for more than 3 seconds, it should be replaced by another image.

If the place changes, the counter should be reset.

```
var secondsUntilImageReplacement = 3,
    counter = 0;

if ( imagePosition == definedPosition ) {
   interval = setInterval(function() {
     if ( counter == secondsUntilImageReplacement ) {
       // Replace Image
     }
     ++counter;
   }, 1000);
}
else {
  window.clearInterval( interval );
  counter = 0;
}
```

Unfortunately the code does not work as I supposed it to do. If I once reach the `definedPosition` the code runs, even I it scroll further (translate the image off the `definedPosition`)

What do I do wrong?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to reinvent setTimeout

Comment: I don't think so. setTimeout only waits for a set time (in my case 3 seconds), but the position of the image has absolutely no effect to the function. Once it's triggered, it runs. I only want to replace the image if it has been on that exact place for 3 secons without interruption.

Comment: Please provide a runable example.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want.
It would be recommend if you provide an fiddle or website.

I think you try, if user is scrolling, to match a position of defined position.
If you matched this, replace after 3secs an image?

```js
var images = [
  'https://image.pixelio.de/000/770/305//player/1--770305-Herbstsch%26ouml%3Bnheit-pixelio.jpg',
  'https://image.pixelio.de/000/770/304//player/1--770304-Weidek%26ouml%3Brbchen%20mit%20Herbstfr%26uuml%3Bchte-pixelio.jpg',
  'https://image.pixelio.de/000/770/229//player/1--770229-Fieber%3F-pixelio.jpg'
];

var index = 0;
// ...your scroll event...
//if ( imagePosition == definedPosition ) {

// this interval is for testing code...
setInterval(function() {
  index++;
  index = (index >= images.length) ? 0 : index; 
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('[data-change-image]').attr('src', images[index]);
  }, 3000);
}, 3000);
// end of if statement}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img data-change-image src="https://image.pixelio.de/000/770/305//player/1--770305-Herbstsch%26ouml%3Bnheit-pixelio.jpg" width="20%">
```